# improve $(document).ready and $( window ).resize and make it more compact

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code
for example

```
var Wwin = $(window).width()

if ( Wwin > 2000 ) { 
    alert ('yes')
} else {    
    alert ('no')    
}
```

I need this code run , every time `$(document).ready` and `$( window ).resize`

for example

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

    var Wwin = $(window).width()

    if ( Wwin > 2000 ) { 
        alert ('yes')
    } else {    
        alert ('no')    
    }

});

$(document).ready(function() {

    var Wwin = $(window).width()

    if ( Wwin > 2000 ) { 
        alert ('yes')
    } else {    
        alert ('no')    
    }

});
```

is there any way to improve this code and make it more compact ?

for example

```
var $MyFunction =  (   var Wwin = $(window).width()
                       if ( Wwin > 2000 ) { 
                            alert ('yes')
                       } else { 
                            alert ('no')    
                       }  )

$( window ).resize(function() {

     $MyFunction

}); 

$(document).ready(function() {

     $MyFunction

});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){} & $( window ).resize(function() {

         $MyFunction

});
```

What do u suggest ?

Comment: try putting that resize code inside document.ready function. Should work

Comment: keeping it separately `$( window ).resize` and `$(document).ready` is better

Comment: I made an edit I think that is the answer you need.

Comment: It makes more sense to use `$(document).on('ready', function(){}` and `$(window).on('resize', function(){}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always make a function.

```
var windowSize = function () {
    if ( $(window).width() > 2000 ) { 
        alert('yes')
    } else {    
        alert('no')    
    }
}
$(document).ready(windowSize);
$(window).resize(windowSize);
```

But keep in mind that resize event will be fired many times.

Comment: remove the spaces between `alert` and your `()` to have a working answer

Comment: @Mivaweb, spaces between `alert` and `()` is non issue

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that :

```
var $MyFunction = function(){alert ($(window).width() > 2000?'yes':'no')};
$( window ).resize($MyFunction); 
$(document).ready($MyFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var resizeHandler = function () {
    if ( $(window).width() > 2000 ) alert('yes');
    else alert('no');
}

$(function() {
    resizeHandler();
    $(window).resize(resizeHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an edit I think that is the answer you need.

```
var $windowSize = function () {
    if ( $(window).width() > 2000 ) { 
        alert('yes')
    } else {    
        alert('no')    
    }
}
$(document).on('ready',$windowSize);
$(window).on('resize',$windowSize);
```

[Why you should use on()](http://blog.letitialew.com/post/28188613275/why-you-should-use-jquery-on-instead-of-bind)
It makes more sense to use `$(document).on('ready', function(){});` and `$(window).on('resize', function(){});`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a function and call it on load and bind it to window resize event.

```
var resizeView = function () {
    if ( $(window).width() > 2000 ) {
        alert('yes');
    } else {
        alert('no')
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeView();
    $(window).resize(resizeView );
});
```